# Laravel catch exception and add message to a messagebag

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4

I have a repository that throws an exception if it can't find a record in the database. Rather than redirect to another page I just want to display a warning alert as the record is not critical to the page but is an "exceptional event".

It's probably best to demonstrate with code:

```
// FxRateRepositoy

public function getRate(/** args **/)
{
  $rate = FxRate::where(.... //query to get the rate
  if (!rate)
    throw new NonExistentCurrencyException(//message);

  return $rate;
}
```

In my start/global.php I have a handler:

```
App::error(function(NonExistentCurrencyException $e)
{
    Session::flash('alert', $e->getMessage());
    return \\ ??
});
```

What to return? I must return a response or the exception continue uncaught. I want to continue to the intended page but with the alert flashed in the session. Is this possible without having to use `try catch` blocks in every place this method is called?

Ass an additional question, assuming this exception may be thrown multiple times in one request, what's the best way to accumulate alert messages and display them? I'm thinking something akin to the validation `messageBag`. Can I just use the global `$errors` variable or should I create a new, specific messagebag for this purpose?

Comment: To that end you should catch the exception directly in the controller and keep going.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you return nothing from `App::error` Laravel will display it's default error page. On the other side you can't return a response because you don't know what response it should be in the error handler.

I suggest you handle it in the controller itself.

You can catch the exception there and flash the message or don't throw an exception at all:

```
$rate = FxRate::where(.... //query to get the rate
if (!rate){
    Session::flash('alert', 'Whoops');
}
```

Also the `findOrFail()` and `firstOrFail` methods might be of use. They throw an `ModelNotFoundException` if the query yields no results:

```
try {
    $rate = FxRate::where(....)->firstOrFail()
    // and so on
} catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e){
    Session::flash('alert', 'Whoops');
}
```

---

As for a messages system, take a look at the [laracasts/flash package](https://github.com/laracasts/flash)

Comment: Yes, I think the idea of catching it in another class and accumulating messages isn't the best idea. I've reverted to just making an error handler and redirecting to an error page instead. Although it would be possible to handle these exceptions and append a messagebag with error messages it muddies the code and makes less maintainable. Thanks for the input though.